# How to backport microphone patches?

Tags: arch-linux, backports, microphone

I'm running Arch Linux on my Dell XPS 13 which works fine except for the microphone which does not record sound. The [wiki of my laptop](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_%282015%29#HDA_mode) says:

> The microphone does not work out-of-the-box, but there are two patches available in kernel 4.1 that fix it (1, 2); it is highly recommended that you backport these into your kernel. Alternatively, you can use altercation's linux-xps13-altAUR kernel, which contains the mic patches"

So, these are the steps that I performed. It's the first time I use backports, so I don't know if these steps are correct.

- Install backports-patched from the user repository
- Select interactive configuration mode
- Select ALX and confirmed
- Reboot

Since the microphone is still not working, how can I check if the backporting was successful?

- `arecord -l` lists the card under the name *PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3263 Analog [ALC3263 Analog]* and as the only device.
- Alsamixer has an entry *Digital* under the capture devices that is set to full volume.
- I don't hear anything when I `aplay ~/test.wav` what was recorded with `arecord -d 10 ~/test.wav`.

<sub>Link to [the question](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1544536) on the Arch Linux forums.</sub>